# Java API to convert DOCx files into 508-complaint PDF

Tags: java, pdf, api, pdf-generation

Our organization is looking for a java library which helps to convert the docx document to 508 complaint pdf.

508 compliance is guidelines for the pdf document, so that people with disabilities can use the screen readers to  read the document without any issue.

More details of guidelines: https://www.section508.gov/

We tried Aspose words java library to convert docx document to pdf. But pdf has not met the guidelines.

Ex: it failed creating TOC tag for table of contents.

I am here to find out that, if there are there any java libraries (paid/opensource) available other than aspose and claims they support 508c guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE!  We're going to need some more information to help you.  For example, what is your price range, or are you only looking for gratis solutions?  Please also include 1 or 2 sentences explaining 508 compliance.

Comment: Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.